# GitHub Team Usage

Tags: git, github, merge

Hi I've just gone through the GitHub [Learn-in-15 minutes tutorial](http://try.github.com/levels/1/challenges/1). GitHub seems very good and easy to pickup. One thing I don't understand is working in a team environment with people who may edit the same files?

From my understanding

- there will be a single remote repo (`origin`)  which contains the latest files of the application.
- Each team member pulls `origin` master
- Each team member can create branches of their own local edit the files, commit the branch and merge with their local `master`.
- Team member can now push their `master` to `origin/master`.

Now what happens if 2 Team Member don't edit the same file.

Origin V1

MemberA  created V2 and pushes
Origin now V2

MemberB still has V1 but has made V3 and pushes it
won't the changes MemberA pushed be rolled back the original V1 because

or is this where the Stage and adding files to stage to push comes into play?

IE it doesnt 'replace' all the files with your push.. but only the ones you have added to your stage/commited??

Answer (score 4):

If you try to push to your remote (`origin` in your example) and the file on that remote has been updated before you attempt to push than your push will be rejected. You will have to `pull` from the remote first and solve any conflicts before you can push.

Otherwise, if there are no conflicts, files are just updated when one pushes to `master`. Keep in mind there is a whole process here. One does not simply push to master :-) (or merge). Sorry for the meme, but I had to.

[image: One does not not simply merge into master]

At its simplest, if a file on the remote has been updated before you've had a chance to push, then you will not be able to push. If the file you changed has not been changed on the remote than your push will be successful.

A basic flow entails pulling into your branch frequently to keep it up-to-date with master.

Comment: hahah what do you mean theres awhole process? what would that be?
Also if we are working for example on a grails project in eclipse.. do we need to manually add the files we have worked on to the staging area or does git automatically pickup the files that have changed..git status i think?

Comment: from your quote At its simplest, if a file on the remote has been updated before you've had a chance to push, then you will not be able to push. If the file you changed has not been changed on the remote than your push will be successful.

when i pull to get that latest version... wont it replace all my files (ones ive edited) with this latest pull...?

Comment: no, it won't replace, but it will let you know of a conflict. it will be on you to resolve that conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Git is wonderful in that it doesn't dictate your workflow -- the steps you take to run from a product owner's ideas through a developer's fingers through testing and into production.  Rather it merely identifies ways for tracking things.  Your process can thus be what ever you'd like.  Some find this openness too confining -- how do you get past the blank page?

[Git-Flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) is a naming convention for branches and methodology of branching and merging that tracks the development process through the various stages.  It is great at offering the structure necessary to work in teams.  It is generally geared towards specific, periodic releases, and thus may be too much for some.

(There's also a git plugin for Git-Flow [here](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/wiki/Installation).)

If Git-Flow is too much, you may want to look to [GitHub Flow](http://scottchacon.com/2011/08/31/github-flow.html) where users merely branch from master, build the feature, test, and merge back into master.

Ultimately, these are just conventions for handling the process, and you can take as much or as little of all or none of them -- based on how well they match the culture of your team.